# How to Use Navigateup Back From Thrird Activity to Second Activity using Intent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, uinavigationbar, subclass

I am developing an android application. In this application,I have 3 Activity one as **Title Activity** and another one as **Subtitle Activity** and another one is **detail Activity**

Now i want to **navigate up** from one activity(**Subtitle Activity**) **to** parent activty(**Title Activity**) by using the below code i perform that operation

**SubTitleActivity:**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcategory_activity);
    actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
listView2= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
Intent intent= getIntent();
final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
actionBar.setTitle(selectedData);
dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
try {
    dbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
cursor=dbHelper.getsubcategory(sqLiteDatabase,selectedData);
String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.SUBCATEGORY };
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.subcategory };
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.subcategory_row,cursor,from,to);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) (listView2.getItemAtPosition(position));
        String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SubcategoryActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedItem);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});


        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id==android.R.id.home)
                {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name=".SubcategoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_subcategory" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity"></meta-data>
        </activity>
```

Now i don't know how to Move From My Detail Activity  to  Subtile Activity  how can we perform that??

DetailActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity);
    actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
detailtext= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


Intent intent= getIntent();
final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
actionBar.setTitle(selectedData);
dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
try {
    dbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
cursor=dbHelper.getdetails(sqLiteDatabase, selectedData);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    detailtext.setText(cursor.getString(0));
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id==android.R.id.home)
    {

        onBackPressed();

    }
```

[image: from Detail Activity i want to move from SubActivity]

Comment: set SubtitleActivity as parent activity for Detail. that should be enough if you use default implementation of Home Button

Comment: `<activity
            android:name=".SubcategoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_subcategory" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity"></meta-data>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".SubcategoryActivity"></meta-data>` am i correct?

Comment: Am i COrrect?? @X3Btel

Comment: What do you want to do when you press back button or home button from `DetailActivity` ?

Comment: @vasanth you have to tell me if I`m correct. But that should bring you back from detail to Subcategory if home is pressed.

Comment: [![Now i am in Detail Activity and i want to Move from that Activity to SubActivity not  Title Activity ][1]][1] 
@X3Btel

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbUGm.png

Comment: [![Now i am in Detail Activity and i want to Move from that Activity to SubActivity not  Title Activity ][1]][1] 
@Henry

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbUGm.png

Comment: Check My Updated Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this in your `DetailsActivity` code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For more info read about the `Tasks and Back Stack` (Especially the `Using Intent Flags` part) here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: `onBackPressed();` was Not Working Plz Check my updated Code @Henry

Comment: I forgot to put `return true;`. I have updated my code. Could you check this one out. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener);
```

and put click listener like:

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               YourActivity.this.onBackPressed();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks but i am Not ready to use toolbar so plz help me by doing actionbar i think we want to use intent there @georgehardcore

Comment: if you are using last version of support library with new design of action bar android.R.id.home won't work, I faced it when I got the support material design year ago. I think you have to implement the Toolbar

Comment: Toolbar for Particular Activity or all Activity??

Comment: Just create one style for all Activities

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example - good example for start or download Google IO https://github.com/google/iosched